# Converting CSV to XML with WSO2 integration studio?

Tags: xml, csv, wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

I'm new in integration studio and i need help with simple task.
I need to load every csv files and transform it to XML files with proxy service.
In every tutorials They show how to do it with REST API, but I need proxy service.
Is anyone know how to do it? I've already creaty a proxy service and import csvmodule.

Just transform csv to xml.

Answer (score 0):

First inrorder to consume your CSV files, you can either create a [File Inbound Endpoint](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.0.0/micro-integrator/use-cases/examples/inbound_endpoint_examples/file-inbound-endpoint/) or a [VFS Proxy Service](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.0.0/micro-integrator/use-cases/examples/file-processing/vfs-transport-examples/). Then convert the CSV content to XML using [CSV Module](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/connectors/csv-module/csv-module-config/) or [Smooks Mediator](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/mediators/smooks-Mediator/), once converted you can use the [File Connector](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/connectors/file-connector/file-connector-example/) or VFS transport again to write the same content to a XML file.